# Combine row depending on their value of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select all columns from my table **properties**, but filter through the records with some conditions.

if a record's compositeKey equqals to another compositeKey, and then the apartment value is not equal to the other, and their group is equal to "----" then combine them into 1 record while adding their apartments together

| compositeKey | apartments | group | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 15 | group1 | blake |
| key2 | 20 | ---- | michael |
| key2 | 21 | ---- | michael |

I would like to select all the values from the table and return them as this output

| compositeKey | apartments | group | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | 15 | group1 | blake |
| key2 | 41 | ---- | michael |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens if `name` is different for same compositeKey in group `'---'`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this script in your postgresql schema !!

```
drop table if exists properties;
create table properties(
compositeKey character(8),
aparments integer,
group_ varchar,
name_ varchar
)

;

insert into properties 
values 
('E124578E',15,'group1','blake'),
('J123456J',20,'---','michael'),
('J123456J',21,'---','michael')
returning *;

;


select 
         compositeKey
        ,sum(aparments) as aparments 
        ,group_
        ,name_
from properties
group by 1,3,4
order by 1
```

Comment: This does work! but it doesnt check whether the matched records with compositeKey whether if their group is equal to "----"